# Spring Profile doesn't work with Aspect annotation

Tags: java, spring, aspectj, spring-annotations, spring-profiles

I declared an aspect that should be run only when a "test" profile is active. Spring doesn't seem to regard the **@Profile annotation** and runs that aspect with or without the "test" profile being activated.

Below is the code block:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Profile;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.AfterReturning;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;

@Aspect
@Configurable
@Profile("test")
public class MyAspect {

  @Autowired
  private MyService service;

  @Pointcut("execution(private * method(..)) && args(table,..)")
  public void myPointcut(StatsParameterTable table) {}

  @AfterReturning(pointcut = "myPointcut(table)")
  public void intercept(StatsParameterTable table) {
    myService.doStuff(table);
  }
}
```

**Spring version**: 4.1.7.RELEASE 
**AspectJ version**: 1.8.2

Comment: Where do you declare your `MyAspect` bean? What's your configuration like?

Answer (score -1):

To make @Profile work, your class should be either @Component or @Configuration (Not Configurable). Try annotating the class with @Component.